# 4 customized subfigures

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I want to insert four subfigures in which the upper row contains only one image that spans over two columns, while the second row contains three subfigures next to each other. Something that resembles this:

[image: As illustrated in the attached image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Should all have different captions? Or something like "a)" for the first picture and so on?

Comment: Note that the image you provided is not a minimal working example. Follow the link contained in my first comment to get an idea of that.

Comment: I think the question is adequate with an image, without MWE. All the OP wanted to know was some guidance in finding a package, and that's easy enough for experienced users to answer. Actual code would have made the question less plain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a MWE the following is just a guess but might be a starting point.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure*}[tb]
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{second}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{third}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{fourth}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{cpation of all figures}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum
here is some custom text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was I was looking for, many thanks @ leandriis